# Python username and password creator

Tags: python

I am creating a program on python that allows you to create a username and password and here's what I have so far:

```
#Code
username = str(input("Please enter a username:"))
print("Your username is",username,",proceed?")
raw_input = input()
if raw_input() == 'no':
    re_u = input("Please re-enter username")
else:
    import getpass
    mypass = getpass.getpass("Please enter your password:")
```

And the trouble i'm receiving is:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
     line 6, in 
    if raw_input() == 'no':
    TypeError: 'str' object is not callable.

Please help

Comment: are you writing this in python 2.7 or 3.x?

Answer (score 1):

In the Line:

```
raw_input = input()
```

If you are using python 2.7, You are overriding the default `raw_input` and making it a string.

If you are using python 3, you are creating a string `raw_string` with the value of `input()`

So, in both cases, when you try to call `raw_input` like a function, you will receive the error.

> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable.

```
if raw_input() == 'no':
```

Here, `raw_input` is a string, not a callable. You can not call it like a function.

Now, so the working code should be like below: (A python 2.7 solution)

```
import getpass

username = raw_input("Please enter a username:")
username_confirmation = raw_input("Your username is " + username + ",proceed?")
if username_confirmation == "No":
    username = raw_input("Please re-enter username")
else:
    password = getpass.getpass("Please enter your password:")

# do something with username and password
```

Comment: If this is Python 3, then `raw_input` isn't a default method anymore, since it was renamed to `input` instead.

Comment: @Makoto I got the feeling that this is python 2, because OP is surely a beginner and using `raw_input()` wrongly. If this is python 3, he shouldn't be familiar with it. Anyway,  I have edited the answer for both the cases.

Comment: `print` became a function in Python 3, and `input` behaves the same as `raw_input` did in Python 2 (as in Python 2, `input` did something distinct too).  I strongly doubt that the OP is using Python 2, but thanks for correcting it.

Answer (score 0):

raw_input is a string, but you're trying to use it as a function with the () at the end of it. use this instead:

```
if raw_input == 'no':
```